# Could not receive a message from the device (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, xcode, installation, ipod-touch

I built and run an iPhone application on **iPod Touch 2.2.1** device, got some problems and made a fix attempt. Now trying to re-build & run the application gives two (2) error popup notes:

> Could not receive a message from the device [OK]

Google couldn't find this! The device itself is working happily, I can even launch and use the app I'm trying to install. iTunes looks like it's still connected... What could be the problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried restarting the iPhone?

Comment: That helped, thanx! Should have thought about it myself, but it's a bit late here (1.30 AM). The mysterious problem is not repeatable, guess device got confused. If you could write how to do reboot as answer, I would accept it for you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Restart the iPhone.

Comment: mmm... how many issues are getting resolved with a restart :)

Answer (score 5):

Restart your iPhone device. Also, restart Xcode. This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using some "cheap" USB cable? This was the cause in my case.

Comment: Original cable here. Still happens.

Answer (score 3):

Just got the same message. I fixed it by connecting my iPhone directly to my Macs USB-Port instead of connecting it to a USB-Hub.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, and it was due to having old WiFi connection settings. I just connect new WiFi in both iMac and iPhone. I never connect via USB. iMac automatically connects to my iPhone and I can debug directly on my iPhone. Sometimes the connection is loose;  in that case, I just go to

-> **Windows** -> **Device and simulators** -> **select my device** -> **right click** -> **connect vai IP address**.

Just enter an IP address from my iPhone WiFi. For that, just go to --> **WiFi of iPhone** -> **info (symbol)**  -> **IP address**.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this messsage, the problem was too many devices (via USB) connected to my MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Received this message recently and tried the steps above, specifically different combinations of restarting the iPhone, disconnecting/reconnecting it, and quitting/restarting Xcode.

In the end, I restarted my comp and it works fine now.